# Cannot find solution for Call to a member function isPasswordValid() on null in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

When i try to log into registered user , I cannot go further than this error.
My authentificator

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserLoginAuthentificatorAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {


    return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $credentials['password'],$user->getSalt());

        // Check the user's password or other credentials and return true or false
        // If there are no credentials to check, you can just return true
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: check the credentials inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

registration controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserLoginAuthentificatorAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {


    return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $credentials['password'],$user->getSalt());

        // Check the user's password or other credentials and return true or false
        // If there are no credentials to check, you can just return true
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: check the credentials inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

I set the security to have algorithm to auto
security.yalm

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: false
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\UserLoginAuthentificatorAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # allow unauthenticated users to access the login form
         - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }


         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I'm a begginer with Symfony I have read more than once the Symfony security chapter. I must have missed somthing. It will be nice if someone could help me with that one

Comment: It looks like you forgot to assign `$this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder` in your authenticator's constructor.

Comment: [enable_authenticator_manager: true](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html#enabling-the-system) implies that you are using the new authenticator capability.  It is is not compatibility with guard authenticators.  Even if you got something working you should probably start a fresh project, decide if you want to use the new authentication system or not and then run make:auth again.

Comment: @Cerad , you're right ttank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Auuthenticator instead of this:

```
public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $credentials['password'],$user->getSalt());
}
```

use this:

```
public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
}
```

---

In security.yaml instead of this:

```
providers:
    users_in_memory: { memory: null }
```

use this:

```
providers:
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
```

---

and instead of this:

```
    main:
        anonymous: false
        lazy: true
        provider: users_in_memory
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\UserLoginAuthentificatorAuthenticator
```

use this:

```
    main:
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
```

---

And in your controller add:

```
    $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
```

after:

```
    $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
```

like this:

```
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help, that was it. I ahd tried those modification before but I was not addressing to the good provider and not assigning the $passwordEncoder. I had to remove the anonymous=true in the security.yalm. I had an error telling that no anonymous was used ans that I had to remove it.

Comment: @phil Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution